# Facebook like button disappears after changing the static permalink to dynamic one!

Tags: permalinks, facebook

The below code works like a charm, but it's a static href!

```
<li class="fb-like fb" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></li>
```

When I change the href to the_permalink, the button disappears!

```
<li class="fb-like fb" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></li>
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you view source, is the_permalink correctly added there?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you forgot to close your PHP code correctly using `?>`, try the following:

```
<li class="fb-like fb" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></li>
```

For the future, you can easily view the source of the page and check if `the_permalink` was correctly inserted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the Time Christine, I forgot to add the question mark here but I wrote it correctly in my codes. That was a localhost problem after all! The facebook like button is working fine in a live server.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

That turned out to be a localhost problem after all! The code is working fine in my server.

Comment: Can you explain ___what___ the "localhost problem" was? Otherwise, this answer isn't much use to anyone who come across the question.

Comment: What I mean is that the problem only occurred locally, but when I moved to the live server, the problem was gone! I don't know why!